# Sphinxsearch periodically throws error searching an rt-index via zf2 db adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sphinx

I'm having an intermittent problem with quite a complex search system. Every once in a while a PHP Daemon I wrote, which adds new content to our database and an RT index for sphinx throws a mysterious exception.

Message is simply "Statement could not be executed".

The code that causes it is (trimmed):

```
<?php
$itemIds = Array( 79555 );
$index = 'doc';
$adapter = $this->dbAdapter;

$qi = function($name) use ($adapter) { 
    return $adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier($name); 
};

$checkSql = '
    SELECT * FROM
        '. $qi( $index ) . '
    WHERE
        id  = ' . (int)$itemIds[0];

$checkStatement = $this->dbAdapter->query($checkSql);
$result = $checkStatement->execute();
```

The exception doesn't seem to occur on any particular trigger, but persists from the time it's first thrown to the time I restart the daemon. I've outputted the sql generated by Zend\DB\Adapter and bar ids being different, there seems to be no diference in the queries from ones that succeed to ones that fail.

There's no associated error in the sphinx logs (that I can see) and if I load neutron/sphinxsearch-api/sphinxapi.php and run `GetLastError()` it returns a blank string.

My thinking is that it's a connection error - or possibly a misconfiguration with the sphinx config making it timeout, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This sounds like you are using persistant connections. At time a connection might be dropped, but your code doesnt account for this, and is still trying to use a connection that has been closed. Maybe try checking for the error, and if get it, reconnects.

Comment: @barryhunter you should add your comment as an answer - it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you are using persistant connections. At times a connection might be dropped, but your code doesnt account for this, and is still trying to use a connection that has been closed. Maybe try checking for the error, and if get it, reconnects.

In short, make the code resilient to the connection occasionally having been closed.